# Find an array element and set it to last in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

In my Ruby on Rails app I have an array:

```
Car.color.values.map{|x| [x.text, x]}.sort
```

This code gives me the following array:

```
[["Beżowy", "beige"], ["Biały", "white"], ["Brązowy", "brown"], ["Czarny", "black"], ["Czerwony", "red"], ["Fioletowy", "violet"], ["Grafitowy", "graphite"], ["Inny", "other"], ["Niebieski", "blue"], ["Perłowy", "pearl"], ["Srebrny", "silver"], ["Szary", "grey"], ["Zielony", "green"], ["Żółty", "yellow"]]
```

Now I want to find this element: `["Inny", "other"]` and set it to last element of an array.
How can I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more generic solution (when you don't know the *exact* value of the element), you can use [`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition), and then concatenate the answers back:

```
arr = [["Beżowy", "beige"], ["Biały", "white"], ["Brązowy", "brown"], ["Czarny", "black"], ["Czerwony", "red"], ["Fioletowy", "violet"], ["Grafitowy", "graphite"], ["Inny", "other"], ["Niebieski", "blue"], ["Perłowy", "pearl"], ["Srebrny", "silver"], ["Szary", "grey"], ["Zielony", "green"], ["Żółty", "yellow"]]
arr.partition { |k, v| v != "other" }.inject(:+)
# => [["Beżowy", "beige"], ["Biały", "white"], ["Brązowy", "brown"], ["Czarny", "black"], ["Czerwony", "red"], ["Fioletowy", "violet"], ["Grafitowy", "graphite"], ["Niebieski", "blue"], ["Perłowy", "pearl"], ["Srebrny", "silver"], ["Szary", "grey"], ["Zielony", "green"], ["Żółty", "yellow"], ["Inny", "other"]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [["Beżowy", "beige"], ["Biały", "white"], ["Brązowy", "brown"], ["Czarny", "black"], ["Czerwony", "red"], ["Fioletowy", "violet"], ["Grafitowy", "graphite"], ["Inny", "other"], ["Niebieski", "blue"], ["Perłowy", "pearl"], ["Srebrny", "silver"], ["Szary", "grey"], ["Zielony", "green"], ["Żółty", "yellow"]]
a.push(a.delete(["Inny", "other"]))
# => [["Beżowy", "beige"], ["Biały", "white"], ["Brązowy", "brown"], ["Czarny", "black"], ["Czerwony", "red"], ["Fioletowy", "violet"], ["Grafitowy", "graphite"], ["Niebieski", "blue"], ["Perłowy", "pearl"], ["Srebrny", "silver"], ["Szary", "grey"], ["Zielony", "green"], ["Żółty", "yellow"], ["Inny", "other"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#rassoc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-rassoc) Searches through the array whose elements are also arrays.

```
arr = [["Beżowy", "beige"], ["Biały", "white"], ["Brązowy", "brown"], .....
arr.push(arr.delete(arr.rassoc("other")))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = a.index(["Inny", "other"])
a.take(i) + a.drop(i + 1) << ["Inny", "other"]
=> [["Beżowy", "beige"], ["Biały", "white"], ["Brązowy", "brown"], ["Czarny", "black"], ["Czerwony", "red"], ["Fioletowy", "violet"], ["Grafitowy", "graphite"], ["Niebieski", "blue"], ["Perłowy", "pearl"], ["Srebrny", "silver"], ["Szary", "grey"], ["Zielony", "green"], ["Żółty", "yellow"], ["Inny", "other"]]
```